# Difference in JSON Serialization of OffsetDateTime Attribute when using Spring Boot and Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, jackson

as I started writing tests for my Spring Boot based REST API I noticed that an `OffsetDateTime` attribute in my DTO is getting serialized differently whether I use the Spring MockMVC to do a request or the Jackson `ObjectMapper`. When using Spring my `@JSONFormat` annotation is used correctly but when using the `ObjectMapper` it isn't.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
public class FooDTO{
    public int id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public OffsetDateTime arrival;

    public fooDTO(int id, OffsetDateTime arrival){
        this.id = id;
        this.arrival = arrival;
    }
}

@RestController
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{id}")
    public fooDTO getFoo (@PathVariable int id) {
        return fooRepository.loadDTO(id);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebMvcTest(FooController.class)
public class FooControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Test
    public void fooTest() {
        FooDTO fooDTO = FooDTO.builder().id(1).arrival(OffsetDateTime.now()).build();
        String fooDTOJSON = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(fooDTO);
        when(fooRepository.loadDTO(1).thenReturn(fooDTO);
        String reponse = mockMvc.perform(request(HttpMethod.GET, "/foo/bar/1").accept(APPLICATION_JSON).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(fooDTOJSON, response);                                                               
    }
```

The Spring MockMVC response looks like this:

```
{"id":1, "arrival": "2020-03-28 12:29:44"}
```

While the fooDTOJSON from the ObjectMapper looks like this:

```
{"id":1, "arrival":{"offset":{"totalSeconds":3600,"id":"+01:00","rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitions":[],"transitionRules":[]}},"nano":697162400,"year":2020,"monthValue":3,"dayOfMonth":28,"hour":12,"minute":29,"second":44,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":88,"month":"MARCH"}}
```

Ideally, I would expect the `ObjectMapper` to return the same result as MockMVC and use my annotation on the DTO. I'd really appreciate someone's help on this even if the solution might be quiet obvious. I'm not too used to working in the Java ecosystem especially Spring.

Answer (score 2):

The Solution that led to the expected result was adding the [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) library (in my case I think it was already present due to Spring(-Boot) or another dependency of my Application) and add the according module to the Jackson Mapper.
The working solution to receive the "correct" JSON String was:

```
String fooDTOJSON = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).writeValueAsString(fooDTO);
```